Where should the ground wire be connected from a generator?
I’m using a 2 pole manual Transfer with fixed Utility neutral & bonded. I have unbonded my generator.
Where should the ground wire be connected coming from the generator if the neutral connects to the bonded utility neutral? Is this correct procedure?


Why are you trying to do whole-house transfer to begin with?

Why do you not have separate ground and neutral wires running between Meter Pan, Transfer & Main?

Why do you want to pay for the electricity from your generator also on your electric bill?

The diagram is incorrect with regard to separation of neutral and ground. The conductor from the utility is technically "neutral." Your own local system provides its own earth ground. All of the neutrals in your local system should connect to bus bars and the utility neutral. Likewise all of the grounds in your local system should connect to bus bars and your own earth ground, which might be ground rods, "ufer" electrode embedded in concrete, or any of several alternatives.
The neutral and the earth ground should be connected ("bonded") to one another in exactly one place. The diagram contains two ground-neutral bonds: one in the meter pan and one in the transfer switch. Either one is okay, but both together is not. Perhaps it's preferable to avoid placing the bond in the meter pan because that enclosure is normally sealed by the utility. The building owner/electrician "cannot" (should not) access the interior of that enclosure without utility approval.
So, you should have a 4-wire connection (two hots, neutral, ground) to the generator (just as you've drawn it) but also a 4-wire connection to the main panel.
It is, or at least it was, common practice to commingle the neutrals and grounds on a single bus bar in whichever panel contains the neutral-ground bond. I think this practice is at the root of much of the confusion. When neutrals and grounds are maintained separately on their own bus bars, and a single jumper or bonding screw connects between the neutral bar and the ground bar (or panel chassis), the separation and bonding are much more evident or obvious.
